# Android change size buttons programatically generic

Tags: android, resize

I have the next problem, I need to resize buttons in my layout depending on my screen size. I know how to write the code for each `Button`, the problem is I have LIKE 50 buttons.
Is there a way to change the size of all buttons like using a for something, and not to write like 100 line codes?

here is an example of the button:

```
<Button 
android:id....
android:layout_width="wrap content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:background="@drawable/..."
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:onClick= ... />
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you not use density-independent pixels? It will automatically scale up or down your buttons based on the resolution keeping the layout identical across.

Comment: i use dpi, but its not enough... because you have a lot of densities with a lot of resolutions

Comment: Can you post your xml here?

Comment: i edit the question and add code

Comment: You are not setting the height and width of your buttons explicitly. You are using wrap_content. Try playing around with them like android:layout_width="10dp" and test it on different resolutions. It should work.

Comment: Are you sure of that?

Comment: Thats not wright. I put size of a view with dp. In same density with different resoultions, de size of the view is the same!